# Double Dimensional Array in Javascript Returning Undefined Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have searched alot and cannot get a clear answer to my problem.

```
var rowCount = 3;
var myCounter = 0;
var myNewArray = new Array();

for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    try {
        myNewArray[myCounter][0] = i;                                   
        myNewArray[myCounter][1] = i;

        myCounter = myCounter + 1;

    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

it is giving and exception saying myNewArray[myCounter] is undefined. Any idea why? I have seen other post and all have shown to declare the array like this or with new Array([]). Nothing is working.
Need help, in advance thank you.

Comment: thank you for the response @torazburo, it worked with adding myNewArray[myCounter] = []; before myNewArray[myCounter] = [1]; as explained below by Quince.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `myNewArray`  is an array but the elements you are trying to access in it do not yet exist (undefined) so you would need to set these elements as arrays

```
 var rowCount = 3;
 var myCounter = 0;
 var myNewArray = new Array();

 for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
     try {
         //set this element as an array if you want to then access it as an array
         myNewArray[myCounter] = [];
         myNewArray[myCounter][0] = i;
         myNewArray[myCounter][1] = i;

         myCounter = myCounter + 1;

     } catch (err) {
         alert(err.message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the response, worked perfectly. :D added myNewArray[myCounter] = []; and got working

Comment: if this issue is solved for then you can mark this as the answer if you want